# PHP Parsing XML to Get All String Values At Multiple Depths

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I've got an XML like the following example:

```
<article>
  <body>
    <title>I <underline><bold>LOVE</bold></underline> Coding</title>
  </body>
</article>
```

I'd like to get the full text of the node **title**.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$title=$xml->xpath('//title')??[];
echo (string)$title;
```

I cannot seem to go deeper and grab the underlined/bold XML parts.

I would like the results to be a string `I LOVE Coding`.

How can I achieve this? I am only getting `I Coding`.

I've also tried `xpath('string(//title)')` but got an empty result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXML is, quite frankly, not a good interface to work with. It's simple as in there's not much to it, but also simple in that there's a fair bit missing, and frequently ends up needing more work anyway.

DomDocument is more full-featured, and by far better to work with, IMO.

```php
$xml = <<<_E_
<article>
  <body>
    <title>I <underline><bold>LOVE</bold></underline> Coding</title>
  </body>
</article>
_E_;

$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadXml($xml);
$x = new DomXPath($d);
$r = $x->query('//title');

var_dump($r[0]->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(13) "I LOVE Coding"
```

Comment: I think it's more the case that SimpleXML is optimised for working with *tree-like* XML, whereas DOM is optimised for working with *markup-like* XML (and HTML). For instance, targeting a specific element in SimpleXML is as simple as `$xml->body->title->underline->bold;`, which in DOM would require either multiple calls to `getElementsByName`, or use of XPath (with a separate `DomXPath` object). And don't forget you can freely mix them - there is basically no penalty for calling `dom_import_simplexml` and `simplexml_import_dom`, as they both wrap the same representation internally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the tags that are inside `<title>` like so:

```php
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$title = strip_tags($xmlFile->body->title->asXML());

echo $title;
```

Or if your XML isn't a file but a string:

```php
$xmlString = '<article>
  <body>
    <title>I <underline><bold>LOVE</bold></underline> Coding</title>
  </body>
</article>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$title = strip_tags($xml->body->title->asXML());

echo $title;
```

Comment: See: https://3v4l.org/SYgPm for an interactive example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`dom_import_simplexml()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) to
retrieve the DOM element, then use the [`textContent`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent)
property:

```php
$xml = <<<XML
<article>
  <body>
    <title>I <underline><bold>LOVE</bold></underline> Coding</title>
  </body>
</article>
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$title = $doc->xpath('//title')[0];
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($title);
echo $dom->textContent;
```

Result:

```
I LOVE Coding
```